# How to display "nothing found" after running a search in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The message is shown before searching. Not able to understand how to show it after the results not found:

```
import { useState, lazy, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as movieAPI from '../../../services/movie-api';
import { Gallery } from 'components/Gallery/Gallery';

import { SearchForm, Button, Label, Input } from './MoviesPage.styled';
import { useSearchParams, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const NotFoundPage = lazy(() => import('../NotFound/NotFoundPage.js'));

export default function MoviesPage() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  let [_, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const handleInputChange = e => {
    setSearchQuery(e.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const { search } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!search) {
      return;
    }
    movieAPI.fetchSearch(search.slice(7)).then(setData);
  }, [search]);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const normalizeSearchQuery = searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (!normalizeSearchQuery) {
      return;
    }
    movieAPI.fetchSearch(normalizeSearchQuery).then(setData);
    setSearchParams(`query=${normalizeSearchQuery}`);
    // setSearchQuery('');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="searchQuery"
          autoComplete="off"
          autoFocus
          placeholder="Search movies"
          value={searchQuery}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Button type="submit">
          <Label>Search</Label>
        </Button>
      </SearchForm>

           {data?.results.length > 0 ? <Gallery data={data} /> : <NotFoundPage />}
    </>
  );
}
```

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function NotFoundPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2> Results not found :(</h2>
      <p>
        <Link to="/">Back</Link>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NotFoundPage;
```

Screenshot from console: http://joxi.ru/MAjPxOGiYdBLDm

I was trying to create a page with a movie searcher button. but the function NotFoundPage is running before it needs to run. So, what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: data && data.results.length === 0 can be the condition for NotFoundPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only render the search results *after* the data has been fetched. In other words, wait until `data` is a non-null value.

Examples:

1. ```
   {data && data.results?.length ? <Gallery data={data} /> : <NotFoundPage />}
   ```
2. ```
   {data
     ? data.results?.length ? <Gallery data={data} /> : <NotFoundPage />
     : null
   }
   ```
3. ```
   {data
     ? data.results?.length ? <Gallery data={data} /> : <NotFoundPage />
     : <div>Searching...</div>
   }
   ```

Another suggestion may be to use an explicit "loading" state.

Example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

...

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const normalizeSearchQuery = searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (!normalizeSearchQuery) {
    return;
  }

  setIsLoading(true);
  try {
    const data = await movieAPI.fetchSearch(normalizeSearchQuery);
    setData(data);
    setSearchParams(`query=${normalizeSearchQuery}`);
  } catch(error) {
    // catch and handle/ignore any rejected Promises or thrown errors
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(true);
  }
};

...

if (isLoading) return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc

return (
  ...
  {data?.results?.length ? <Gallery data={data} /> : <NotFoundPage />}
  ...
);
```